# Amazon SageMaker Unsupported content-type application/x-image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have a tensorflow/keras based CNN model deployed in Sagemaker.

Now to invoke the inference, I followed this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/classify-your-own-images-using-amazon-sagemaker/)

Below code snippet

```
def inferImage(endpoint_name):
    # Load the image bytes
    img = open('./shoe.jpg', 'rb').read()
    runtime = boto3.Session().client(service_name='sagemaker-runtime')

    # Call your model for predicting which object appears in this image.
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName=endpoint_name,
        ContentType='application/x-image',
        Body=bytearray(img))
    response_body = response['Body']
    print(response_body.read())
```

When I run this code, I get error

`Unsupported content-type application/x-image`

What am I missing? Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: How did you end up solving your problem? Mind sharing? :)

Comment: I'm facing same issue,how did you get it solved ?

Comment: @Prany I created my own custom docker to deploy the model as a service. For inference, I call this service.

Comment: Thanks for reply, is it possible to share some context on how did you create custom docker and all. May be add as an answer as well. It will help !

Comment: It is some internal code in my workplace so I can't share. But this guide seems to be doing the same thing as I did. I did not follow it so I can't really verify it but the process seems correct. https://towardsdatascience.com/brewing-up-custom-ml-models-on-aws-sagemaker-e09b64627722

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Did you use SageMaker python sdk?
If yes, you could refer to this README https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_python.rst
and provide your own input_fn() to deal with application/x-image data.

If you don't provide your customized input_fn() in the user script, the default input_fn can only handle 3 types: "application/json", "text/csv" and "application/octet-stream"

The exception is thrown here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container/blob/1e74bc6440cdd7e083d15026869e021c5ab504a4/src/tf_container/serve.py#L239

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken to https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_python.rst

Is there another resource you can point us to for understanding how to implement this custom `input_fn()` for image payload handling?