# Error in Call to Sagemaker Endpoint with Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I try make predictions with a TensorFlow-Keras model in Sagemaker, but recive the next errors:

In Amazon Cloudwatch, for Lambda Function:

```
An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from model with message "
{
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type: application/x-image"
}
```

In Cloudwatch, for Sagemaker:

```
F external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:426] Check failed: index >= 0 && index < num_total_dims Invalid index from the dimension: 3, 0, C
```

Data is an image send in base64, the Lambda function convert this img to bytes, Lambda Function is:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = data['foto']
    image = base64.b64decode(payload)
    print(type(image))
    
    try:
        response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                            ContentType='application/x-image',
                                            Body=image)
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error en inferencia:")
        print(e)

    return payload # only for test
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using SageMaker v2. With v2 you don't directly set `content_type` instead you set the content type in a `Serializer` instance. You can either do this in the Predictor's constructor or by setting `predictor.serializer` afterwards. Note that you can use an already created serializer class that allows you to specify a `content_type` or alternatively implement a class where you customize it to handle `content_type`.

Answer (score 2):

I think `content_type='application/x-image'` is not supported

[how to handle application/x-image ?](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container/issues/138)

[SageMaker TensorFlow Serving Container supports the following Content-Types for requests:](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container/blob/master/README.md#prepost-processing)

SageMaker TensorFlow Serving Container supports the following Content-Types for requests:

- application/json (default)
- text/csv
- application/jsonlines

And the following content types for responses:

- application/json (default)
- application/jsonlines

you can check this answer [Amazon SageMaker Unsupported content-type application/x-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643081/amazon-sagemaker-unsupported-content-type-application-x-image) which has few suggestions.

> You need create your own custom docker to deploy the model as a service.